# Traveling from SFO to MNL. Making 2 stops in China. Do I need a visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit, china

Traveling from SFO to Manila. We're making a technical stop in Wuhan and a layover in Guangzhou. I'll be in China for less than 24 hours. After that I will take a flight from Guangzhou to Manila.

Do I need a travel visa? I called the Chinese embassy, they said no I don't. Different travel agencies say no. My airline says yes.

Do I need one or not?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by check-in staff at airports (to determine whether to let you board the flight):

> Visa required, **except** for holders of confirmed onward air
>   tickets in transit through Guangzhou (CAN) to a third country,
>   for a max. transit time of 24 hours.
>
> Transit **incl. multiple stops** within China (People's Rep.)
>      is permitted at Guangzhou (CAN) only when the **first transit
>      point is Beijing (PEK)**. The total maximum transit time is
>      24 hours.

Depending on the country, even a technical stop not involving clearing immigration may count as transit, and Timatic doesn't indicate this **not** being the case.

The determining question here is: **does the technical stop at Wuhan count as a transit point?** Timatic doesn't clarify this, unfortunately.

What you need to do is call the airport, ask to speak with a supervisor of the ground handling agent responsible for China Southern and ask this specific question (the flight number is CZ 660).

If the technical stop in Wuhan **does** count as a transit point, you will need a transit visa: because multiple-stop visa-free transit at Guangzhou is only allowed if the first transit point is Beijing.

If the technical stop in Wuhan does **not** count as a transit point (in which case **get it in writing** from the supervisor), you do **not** need a visa

Once again, it is the ground handling agent responsible for China Southern at SFO that you have to contact, because their interpretation of the info in Timatic is **the** thing that determines whether you'll get on the flight.

Comment: "If the technical stop in Wuhan does count as a transit point, you will need a transit visa" --> not if the OP isn't a US citizen.

Comment: @dda If Wuhan counts as a transit point, that makes it the first one, which disqualifies OP from using multiple-stop visa-free transit at Guangzhou (because the first transit point must be Beijing) regardless of their nationality

Comment: I don't understand why this answer has received multiple down votes. It presents detailed information raising questions about whether a visa is needed, which nobody has refuted. US citizenship seems like a reasonable assumption given the question. And even if a visa is not needed, the airline denying boarding is a real concern if they are referring to ambiguous information. This is not just hypothetical, since the OP says the airline told them a visa is needed.

Comment: @dan1111 Like I said, whether OP's American is irrelevant in this case because of the rules in Guangzhou. In fact I removed the Quote about Wuhan, as it's actually redundant in this specific case

Comment: @Coke fair enough. Initially I assumed that US or Canadian nationality applied to all the guidance quoted. Anyway, the point was I agree with this answer.

Comment: Since when does Timatic purport to know which visas a traveler **whose nationality is unknown** needs or doesn't need?

Comment: @HenningMakholm When a generalised search for a given country is performed, it states that. The Guangzhou transit rule thus applies to everyone not visa-exempt for China

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a visa, if you are less than 24 hours in China from first scheduled arrival time to scheduled departure time. [Source](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/free-transit-24hour.htm)

Comment: According to the link you posted, "Generally speaking, the 24-hour direct transit allows aliens to have multiple stops in China as long as they leave the country within 24 hours. Nevertheless, if transiting in Weihai, Wuhan, Xian or Zhengzhou, US and Canadian citizens cannot enjoy multiple-stop transit." OP states that they are  making a stop in Wuhan, so that may exclude that option (perhaps depending on whether you have to get off the plane and clear immigration at the tech stop?).

Comment: True. But I don't think the OP is American.

Comment: Also, ***while this needs to be checked,*** I seem to remember that the Wuhan etc restriction only applies to people who actually get off the plane.

Comment: @dda Timatic mentions no such thing

Comment: @Coke and that could be why the airline thinks the OP needs a visa. Doesn't mean it isn't the case. Wouldn't be the first time either...

Comment: @dda, the OP asks about visas for a trip originating in the U.S., without saying anything about their nationality. Isn't U.S. citizenship a reasonable assumption? If that's not the case, I think the question needs to be clarified.

Comment: @dan1111 The Q doesn't need clarification: OP's nationality is irrelevant

Comment: OP's citizenship is relevant. Wuhan exception applies only to US/Canada citizen. Furthermore, if the OP stays on the plane in Wuhan, she is (not yet) applying for the TWOV, as she won't pass through immigration...

Comment: @ajd Wuhan might Count as a Transit stop regardless, in which case transiting Guangzhou directly afterwards won't be possible visa-free

Comment: You need to **apply** for the TVOW, in person, with your passport, an immigration form, at a dedicated Immigration counter. Hard to do that sitting on a plane...

Comment: @dda "You need to apply for the TVOW, in person, with your passport" And how should check-in staff know that? That may well be the case in China, but in a lot of countries even a technical stop counts as TWOV